# Switch tabs in Safari - Shortcut (⌘ + ⌥ + Arrow)

Tags: macos, keyboard, safari

I would like to know if there is a way to switch tabs in Safari with the shortcut used in Chrome (⌘ + ⌥ + Arrow).

Right now with OS X El Capitan, you can switch between tabs but just up to the 9th one with ⌘ + number.

I find it way much easier to switch tabs with the arrows compared to the numbers plus you can get to all the tabs instead of the nine first ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ctrl + tab` to switch to the next tab (equivalent to `⌘ + ⌥ + >`) and `ctrl + shift + tab` to switch to the previous tab (equivalent to `⌘ + ⌥ + <`).

You can use this on Safari, Chrome and Firefox, basically with any app that has tabs.

Comment: Awesome! Great reply, right to the point. Now my life is much easier.

Comment: happy to help :)

Answer (score 3):

Go to system preference > keyboard > Shortcuts. Choose "App shortcuts" then press the + button. You can add a shortcut to Safari by selecting it, type the exact command you want as it appears in the menu "Show Previous Tab" then enter the shortcut you want.